# How to correctly write the OR queries in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a matching app with Firebase x flutter.

The goal is to create a function that filters field values from Firestore's userCollection to retrieve documents that match the condition.

The three arguments are as follows.

- String? myUid: my document ID.
- String? selectedLanguage: A variable that contains a string indicating the language code, such as 'en', 'es', etc.
- List<String?> meNativeLanguage: A variable that contains two strings of language codes such as 'en', 'es', etc.

About "queried_language" field, it contains a string such as 'en', 'es', etc.

I executed the following code, but I cannot get any document IDs that matche the conditions. There’s no error messages on the console.

```
static Future<void> getUnmatchedUser(
String? myUid,
List<String?>? selectedLanguage,
List<String?>? meNativeLanguage,
List<String?>? selectedGender,) async{   
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await _userCollection
      .where('matched_status', isEqualTo: false)
      .where('progress_marker', isEqualTo: false)
      .where(FieldPath.documentId, isNotEqualTo: myUid)
      .where("native_language", arrayContains: selectedLanguage![0])      
      .where(Filter.or(
         Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: meNativeLanguage![0]),
         Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: meNativeLanguage[1]))) 
      .limit(4) 
      .get();  
}
```

The following two points were troubleshooted in advance.

- (1) Argument variables are not null at runtime.
- (2) When the function is performed under the condition that only the where method using the OR operator is excluded from the above code, document IDs that match it can be obtained.

Based on the above, I think the problem is in the where method part using OR query.

The way of using OR query followed the official guide below.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?_gl=1*lz88cl*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTE2NzA2MjkzOC4xNzA3OTU4MzM0*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcwNzk1ODMzNC4xLjAuMTcwNzk1ODMzNC4wLjAuMA..

Please tell me what the problem is, I would appreciate it.

=========================================================
According to the advice from comments,　I used the hard-coded values to perform a built test like below.

```
  static Future<String?> getUnmatchedUser(
    String? myUid,
    List<String?>? selectedLanguage,
    List<String?>? meNativeLanguage,
    List<String?>? selectedGender,
    ) async{  
        try { 
          QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await _userCollection
            .where('matched_status', isEqualTo: false)
            .where('progress_marker', isEqualTo: false)
            .where(FieldPath.documentId, isNotEqualTo: myUid)
            .where("native_language", arrayContains: 'en') 
            .where(Filter.or(
              Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: 'ja'),
              Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: 'es'))) 
            .limit(4) 
            .get();  

          print('querySnapshot.docs.length == ${querySnapshot.docs.length}');   

            if (querySnapshot.docs.isEmpty) {return null;}
            if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
              List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = querySnapshot.docs;
              docs.shuffle();                                    
              DocumentSnapshot docSnapshotFirst = docs[0];
              print("talkuserUid: Document[0] ID: ${docSnapshotFirst.id}");
              return docSnapshotFirst.id;
            }    
              return null;
      } catch (e) {
        print('getUnmatchedUser: ERROR == $e');
        return null;
      }
    }
```

- Supplementation:

  - In the if statement, if the document is get, it shuffles the array and returns the id of the [0] element (Please ignore them, as they are not relevant in this debug print).

Below is screenshots from the Firestore console and VScode console of two documents that I think match all conditions, yet that is not returned.

[9lCMFwOVL80Oc9NtXmRu_fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCS60.png)  [9lCMFwOVL80Oc9NtXmRu_console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfVXN.png)  [u2iftdNbIM0teYtUeen2_fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Qzy.png)  [u2iftdNbIM0teYtUeen2_console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sugvh.png)

On device with Uid: u2iftdNbIM0teYtUeen2, 'querySnapshot.docs.length == 1' is expected, but it's 0.
(In the screenshots, the reason the process is repeated multiple times is that the function is being executed in a retry function and will be retried until the document succeeds)

Comment: 1) Since you've done lots of troubleshooting already, can you reproduce the problem with hard-coded values? If so, please share that code rather than the more complex code you have now. 2) I'd also recommend removing the code sample from the documentation, as that doesn't have any problem. 3) Execute the query, and show us the output. E.g. `print` the number of query results, to show that there are none. 4) Finally, please show a screenshot from the Firestore console of a document that you think matches all conditions, yet that is not returned.

Comment: 5) I'd also add a `try-catch` block around the `get()` call, to ensure no exceptions go unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Frank.  Following your instructions, I have executed the function using the hardcoded values and appended screenshots of the results of the execution with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to match the `queried_language` with:

```
Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: 'ja'),
Filter("queried_language", isEqualTo: 'es')))
```

But if we look at the screenshot, `queried_language` is an array - so you'd need [use `arrayContains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to see if that array contains a specific value.

If you want to test for one of multiple values, you can use `arrayContainsAny` rather than an `Or` filter with multiple conditions.